# Custom ajax menu load content (image)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I am trying to create a page with list items and if you click on one of the items you will basically see the image. (each list item have differed image)

Images will be pretty big, so I think the best way is to load (ajax?!) them only when item is called (list item is pressed)(as you can see in my gif example).

It is basically like a ajax menu, if you press the menu item, old content will slide out and the new content will slide in.

List will be big (around 30 items).

**How can I create this kind a ajax menu ?**

Could someone please tell the best way to do this?

[image: Action which I need]

Comment: how did you create the gif ? what software ? nice !

Comment: hhhhh - silly me - but i think its too big for me to use this for such a little feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need  : something like this [Data_URI_scheme]

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot">
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

this way - youll have the picture in the document. but the page will load slower - but when it done loading - youll have all the pic already there.

another way :  is to **preLoad** the images - so you **wont** have **delay** problems.

the picture should'nt be so big. - and their size should be optimized for web display.

If you want your animation to be smooth - you have to preload the first image - but you DONT KNOW what is the first image !! -

```
$.preloadImages = function()
{
  for(var i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++)
  {
    jQuery("<img />", {style:'display:none'}).attr("src", arguments[i]);
  }
}

$.preloadImages("img2_thumb.jpg", "img1_thumb.jpg",
"img3_thumb.jpg");
```

Comment: Ok it will preload images. But how about this list item, how can I target specific image and show it?

Comment: this line : `jQuery("<img />", {style:'display:none'}).attr("src", arguments[i]);` will conenct via `get` to download the image so they are in your browser cache now. so now you can reference to the original image location ( same image name !!) and it will take it from the cache.(unless there is a header - `no cache` in the response.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = document.createElement('img')
img.scr = 'http://...'
document.body.appendChild(img)
```

this will load the image dynamically